# Summer 14 and Price books

Tags: pricebook, clone

[image]

Since Summer 14 released this weekend every time I try and clone a product I get the below error message and I don’t understand what its saying?  I think something changed with the price book in the new release. Any ideas?

It doesn’t happen when I create a new product and type all the data in manually…very much a pain but it works.  The following is the trigger in question I believe

```
trigger PriceBookEntryUpdate on Product2 (before insert,after insert, before update) {
  List<User> userDetails=[Select u.Email, u.Id from User u];
  Map<String , Id> userMap= new Map <String,Id>();
    for (User user : userDetails){
        userMap.put(user.Email,user.Id);

    }

if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
if(Trigger.isBefore){
 //Before trigger starts    
    for(Product2 prod : Trigger.new){
            if(prod.PME_Text__c!=NULL ){
                    prod.PME__c=userMap.get(prod.PME_Text__c.trim());
            }
            if(prod.AE_Text__c!=NULL ){
                         prod.AE__c=userMap.get(prod.AE_Text__c.trim());
            } 
            if((Trigger.isInsert) &&(prod.Product_Status_Code1__c!='6EOL' && prod.Product_Status_Code1__c!='8INAC')){  
                prod.IsActive=true; 
            }
    }
}
 //After trigger starts-creation of PriceBookEntry Record
 if(Trigger.isAfter){
Id StdPrcId=[Select id from PriceBook2 where isStandard=true limit 1].id;
List<PricebookEntry> pbList= new List<PricebookEntry>();
for(Product2 p : Trigger.new){
    PricebookEntry pb=new PricebookEntry(Product2Id=p.id,PriceBook2Id=StdPrcId,UnitPrice=(p.unit_Cost_default__C==null?0:p.unit_Cost_default__C),IsActive=true);
    pbList.add(pb);
}
 try{ 
insert pbList;    } catch(Exception e){system.debug('Error :' +e.getMessage());}
}
}
}
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this but got: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20119: ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CPRICEBOOKENTRY", line 642 ORA-00001: . . .  Dopey? Bashful? Somebody's been watching too much Disney.

Comment: hah yeah.. Should this be a ticket?

Comment: Actually, clone already copies over all price book entries for a product. Since you are creating a standard price book entry for the product when it's created, and then cloning it, the clone is creating a standard price book entry, and your trigger is as well. I think that is causing the conflict.

Comment: The Oracle code does indeed have seven modules. I've seen most of the dwarves already at some point. There's a question on here about that. Your best bet is to log a case so salesforce can fix it.

Comment: Please log a case! We want to hear about it when anything breaks after a release.

Comment: Hi Eric. Any response from SFDC yet?

Comment: It was closed, I haven't heard anything about it.  I will bring it up to the salesgirls

Comment: Seems like this should maybe be closed? Dwarfy problems *should* be closed quite quickly.

Comment: See also: [Salesforce, Oracle and the Seven Dwarfs](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Seven Dwarfs error that is several releases old. It is almost certainly fixed by now.

Comment: I may not get this issue for price books,  bit I've still gotten a seven dwarves error, I'm fine with this closing tho

Answer (score 0):

To automatically create a pricebook entry when a single product is created or cloned (clone does this by default)  We have a separate piece of code for multiples (bulk inserts) which will never be clones.  Btw, we don't use price books.  This is stubbed out to be able to use standard SF quoting features.

```
trigger insertPBE on Product2 (after insert) {
  Pricebook2 standardPriceBook = [SELECT Id from Pricebook2 where Name='Standard Price Book'];
  if(trigger.New.size() <= 1) { //clone would be single record
    try {               
      Product2 product = trigger.New[0];
      //grab existing pricebook entry
      PriceBookEntry pbe = [Select Id from PricebookEntry where Product2Id = :product.Id];
      if(pbe == null)
        pbe = new PricebookEntry(); //create a new one if necessary         
      pbe.Product2Id = product.Id;
      pbe.IsActive = true;
      pbe.Pricebook2Id = standardPriceBook.Id;
      pbe.UnitPrice = 1.00;
      upsert pbe;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { return; }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your after trigger creates PriceBookEntry for inserted Products. When you try to clone a Product with PriceBookEntry, the functionality clones both of them (Product and PBE).

With the Summer '14 Release, your trigger fires after Product creation and before PBE creation. The clone functionality tries to clone the PBE after your trigger has already created it. The database can't allow 2 PBEs with the same currency in the same Price Book for the same Product - therefore, an common.exception.SfdcSqlException is thrown.

You can try to create the PBE from an asynchronous (@future) method. Execute this method in your after trigger and pass the product id (or set of product ids) as parameter. In the future method you can check whether PBE already exists for this product id, or not. If not you can create one.