# Strange error on product clone

Tags: exception, clone

[image]

Anybody seen errors like this before? Any fixes? I'm expecting this to be something deep down in the Salesforce platform and not something I've done but any guidance appreciated.

(I notice Sneezy has made an appearance - and looking around the web it seems that other dwarves are available ;-) )

Comment: Peripherally relevant [fun read](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs).

Comment: I shall keep an eye out for the others and check them off as I go. Only 6 more to go ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by adding an entry into the Standard pricebook that is fired by an after insert trigger when cloning a product. When the trigger fires there is (probably) an entry that has been added to the Standard Pricebook that isn't returned by a SOQL query and so my code thought a new one had to be added explicitly thereby causing an exception as there were now 2 PBEs in the same pricebook for the same product (and currency).

My solution was to set the function checking for the preexisting PBE to be a future method and so the PBE was selectable and updated as necessary in code. Stopping the duplicate PBE fixed the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation from Oracle may help:

> ORA-06512: at stringline string
>
> **Cause**: Backtrace message as the stack is unwound by unhandled
> exceptions.
>
> **Action**: Fix the problem causing the exception or write an
> exception handler for this condition. Or you may need to contact your
> application administrator or DBA.

Sounds like a ticket to salesforce is in your future. Good Luck!

Alternatively you can remove lines of your code until you get it to work, then add them back in to see what causes it. Sometimes it is your code doing it but the error is not very specific