# ORA-20025 converting lead to contact

Tags: trigger, contact, lead-conversion, web2lead

I am trying to convert lead to contact and I get this error:

```
ORA-20025 common.exception.SfdcSqlException`
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CACCESS", line 2399`
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CACCESS", line 585`
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CACCESS", line 656
ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.CTASK", line 552
ORA-06512: at line 1

{call cTask.insert_tasks(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}

{call cTask.insert_tasks(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}`
```

I posted to SF community, spoke to a support member at SF.
 She said that if the community will not answer, one of their support specialists will pick it up. (which they did not thus far)

[SF community post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000MJMsIAO)

I have read through most of the material about this error but no one seems to have resolved this.

My **code** is executed **after insert**:

```
Trigger AutoConvertLead2Contact on Lead (after insert) {

 for (Lead lead: Trigger.new) {
      if (!lead.isConverted && lead.LeadSource == 'אינטרנט') {
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(lead.id);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
        }
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that since its executed **after insert**  it is somewhat too fast to convert right away and that it should be triggered a little but later...mmm
Has anyone encountered this ORA?
Anyone managed to solve the matter?
Thanx

Comment: You just got yourself a dwarf! http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs

Comment: @RobinDeBondt that still does not solve my problem...any ideas?

Comment: When you see one of the dwarfs pop up, it means an internal platform error has occurred. Your only shot is to contact sfdc support again, as it can only be diagnosed by them.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt thanx....could not open a support ticket with sfdc...by phone they said to open a community question and their experts will pick it up...strange way to support customers when its a platform error...any ideas on that?

Comment: I did see just lately that one of our customers with premier support can log cases using the normal help & training route, but another customer without premier support only sees 'ask the community' when following the same route. So maybe they removed the ability to log cases as any customer?
I would try recontacting support, stating this is clearly a platform error the community will be of no help with.

Comment: The redesign of H&T makes it much harder to log a case as a customer, and I'm not sure why. Here's the click path: Click on Technical Support, then Contact Us, then a Topic (Setup, probably), then a Subtopic, *then a question*, and then there's an option at the bottom to "Log a New Case".

Comment: @ChristianCarter - I agree, I find that opening cases sometimes has to be done via a chat session (and I have premier support)

Comment: does this problem occur if not using a right-to-left language? also, you could look at doing the work in @future

Comment: I just tweeted @asksalesforce (Salesforce Support) to ask them to look at this and get involved. Hopefully, someone from Salesforce will jump-in quickly to assist.

Comment: Do you have a Twitter account? @asksalesforce would like to help and will open a Case for you if I can get you in contact with them.  Here's a link to the tweet: https://twitter.com/asksalesforce/status/682624856106643456 from `^RG`.

Comment: I did manage to open a ticket after having SF on the phone...I was disappointed to get their reply: "As I understand that Web to Lead is not generating from Oracle platform, which requires Developer Support and Developer support is currently available only to our premier customers and partners. We apologize for any impact this may be having on you.

We support our standard customers and partners through the developer support boards at https://developer.salesforce.com/. If you have a developer support question, are looking for technical documentation, best practices, "

Comment: code samples and other ways to speed your development time the developer forums are the place for just that. We have dedicated support agents that work the boards to answer questions and review questions to ensure that you get a response.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I was able to assist. Don't allow them to close the case on you once it gets opened just because you don't have premium support! I've seen that happen before.

Comment: @crmprogdev - this is ^RG's answer: Hi Jud, Are hands are pretty tied as well here. I suggest reading through the resources provided by your case owner. Or asking our #askforce community here on Twitter. ^RG

Comment: I might be naive but I asked him: I don't understand how such a corporation does not support its own system's glitches??

Comment: I take it your case got closed? In my view, ultimately these things come from the top down as to how they're going to be addressed and prioritized. E.G: Is it more important to support customers by fixing fundamental platform bugs or to deliver "new features" like Lightning? That's what @Benioff gets paid the big bucks to make decisions and set policies on.

Comment: I am not sure where my case stands?? communication stopped after they let me know they will not be taking care of this. I think their policies are bad as conserving customers is cheaper then bringing in new ones...