# Oracle(!) storage limit error, even though plenty of space left

Tags: limits, oracle, storage-limit

I clicked Save and got the error:

```
common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20003: ORA-06512: at 
"GRUMPY.CSTORAGELIMIT", line 252 ORA-06512: at "GRUMPY.CSTORAGELIMIT", line
 734 ORA-06512: at "GRUMPY.CSTORAGELIMIT", line 785 ORA-06512: at 
"GRUMPY.CSAVEUTILS", line 429 ORA-06512: at 
"GRUMPY.CSTANDARDENTITYDATATEMPLATE", line 2085 ORA-06512: at line 1 {call 
cStandardEntityDataTemplate.insert_stdentdatas(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
?,?,?,?,?,?,?)} {call 
cStandardEntityDataTemplate.insert_stdentdatas(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
```

But in System Overview I see that I have only used 13% of 200MB (it's a developer sandbox).

It was not a one-off: again clicking Save (a change on a Case record) gave the same message. And clicking again and again doesn't help. I also get the same error when trying to change a different Case record. Clearly some storage limit is exceeded, but I don't know which.

According to Salesforce's trust site, there's nothing wrong with the instance - CS86.

Comment: You've managed to see one of the [dwarfs](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs). Logging a case for support will be your only option.

Comment: I have also seen this message before... And just ignored it. After some time it just disappeared. Maybe open a case by Salesforce...

Comment: Well, I can't simply ignore it. I need to change this record. So I just have to wait? The alternative is to log a case, but it's a sandbox so that's always problematic. I'll go for the wait option first.

Comment: Logged a case with Salesforce as well... I cannot simply use another sandbox, as this particular sandbox has all the data for development and tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that it was not a problem with Data Storage, but with File Storage. But Monitor > System Overview only shows Data Storage, so I had not thought about File Storage. Also, the Oracle error suggested that data was stored, not a file.

This was discovered by Salesforce support, and quickly solved by myself.