# System.SObjectException: ORA-20001 when deploying Changeset for users

Tags: apex, data-loader, schedulebatch, static-resources

I'm deploying an apex class and Test class which is running successfully and covering 84% test coverage in sandbox however when deploying it in Prod, I'm running in to below issue. I have included Static Resource in the changeset. Any ideas what is wrong with it? The Static resource consist of a CSV file that includes User data (Name, email, Username , lastlogindate).

```
istest
public class TestScheduleInactiveUser {
    @istest static void ScheduleInactiveUser(){
       
     List<sObject> ls = Test.loadData(User.sObjectType, 'UserLoadTest');
        
      
         Test.startTest();
            ScheduleInactiveUser fc=new ScheduleInactiveUser();
            Database.executeBatch(fc);
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }
}
```

> Error: System.SObjectException: ORA-20001: ORA-06512: at
> "DOC.CPROFILE", line 1128 ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at
> "DOC.CPROFILE", line 2940 ORA-06512: at line 1 SQLException while
> executing plsql statement: {?=call
> cProfile.get_user_type(?)}(00eP0000000bIq5)

```
Stack Trace: 
Class.System.Test.loadData: line 53, column 1 Class.TestScheduleInactiveUser.ScheduleInactiveUser: line 5, column 1
```

Comment: The fact that this crashed in production and not in the sandbox makes me think that production data may be what's causing it. Is it possible that these users already exist in production but not in the sandbox?

Comment: There are no existing users production in the profile that I'm loading in. Does that matter? I also created some users in production too, that didn't work either. I've looked everywhere online, couldn't get any solution. I'm thinking to contact Salesforce support.

Comment: You probably should. See TSmith's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you just tracked down one of the seven dwarfs :) Check out [Salesforce, Oracle and the Seven Dwarfs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs)

You need to contact support and let them know [Doc](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Doc#:%7E:text=Doc%20is%20the%20leader%20of,other%20dwarfs%20look%20for%20guidance.) is on the loose! Quickly, before he gets away.