# Salesforce Internal Error: HAPPY.CMETAACCESS

Tags: gack

We have created our own 2nd generation package and trying to install it in our org, but getting the following error:

```
1.  ORA-20001: 
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 665
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 848
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 799
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 784
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.SITEDEVCOMPONENT", line 718
ORA-06512: at line 1


{call SiteDevComponent.load_sitecomponents(?,?,?,?)}
: ORA-20001: 
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 665
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 848
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 799
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CMETAACCESS", line 784
ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.SITEDEVCOMPONENT", line 718
ORA-06512: at line 1


{call SiteDevComponent.load_sitecomponents(?,?,?,?)}
```

Has anyone encountered something like this before? Any tips would be helpful around the potential causes based on Oracle errors.

Comment: Does [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/336208/system-sobjectexception-ora-20001-when-deploying-changeset-for-users/336209#336209) help? You need to contact SF Support. Happy is on the loose!

Comment: I went ahead and associated this question with the one @Tsmith answered. There's really nothing folks outside Salesforce can do about dwarf errors - please do open a case; those really aren't supposed to happen!

Comment: Also see [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/41155/2984). It's one of my favorites.