# Batchable: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Phoenix driver closed because server is shutting down

Tags: gack, batchapexerrorevent

In my full sandbox, I have a batchable that reschedules itself in the `finish()` method. This job has been running for 2+ years; rescheduling itself many times a day

On August 1 at 2231h Pacific, `Setup | Apex Jobs` reported:

```
First error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Phoenix driver closed because server is shutting down
```

So, I know there's a certain pride in collecting [Seven Dwarfs errors](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs) but this is a new one - to the batchable it acts like an uncaught exception

Sadly, this batchable [did not implement `Database.raisesPlatformEvents`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm) so the error took a few days to detect.

Not sure there is an answer to this except to implement `Database.raisesPlatformEvents` but for those reading this - another thing to worry about, albeit unlikely, in building robust systems.

Comment: One assumes this is [apache phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html#SQL_Client) related and some issue with the connection to the database that leaked through into storing the batchable/schedulable state. I assume you didn't see this more than this once?

Comment: so, far, observed only once

Comment: observed twice, same fullcopy sandbox org as before

Comment: Did you implement the marker interface yet?

Comment: @PhilW - if you mean by _marker interface_ the `Database.raisesPlatformEvents` then yes, I did implement.

Comment: Any useful info from it?

Comment: useful? NOPE - no more data than exposed by `Setup | Apex Jobs` ; what was relevant to me was that I built a framework where the job could be auto-rescheduled in the event of this error recurring