Oracle exception updating Account record
On the Account SObject I have defined a validationRule which checks that the billing country of a record must be the same as parent account's billing country if it is defined
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(ParentId))
    , BillingCountry <> Parent.BillingCountry
)

I thought this to be a simple enough validation rule, however when doing CRUD operations on the account with this validation rule active, I get the following exception
Validation Formula "Account_Parent_BillingCountry" Invalid (ORA-20001: 
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.YACCESSUTILS", line 255
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CACCESS", line 3304
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CACCESS", line 2919
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call cAccess.check_entity_access_proc_ncu(?,?,?,?,?,?,gUtil.gtypes_bool_to_boolean(?),gUtil.gtypes_bool_to_boolean(?),gUtil.gtypes_bool_to_boolean(?),gUtil.gtypes_bool_to_boolean(?))}(EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, 0010o00002qgw0H, EXCLUDED, true, false, true, false, true, true); [conn=STANDARD:6:6:3241:58657])

What am I missing? Should I create a new lookup field instead of using the standard?
Should I move this to a mandatory lookup filter instead of a validation rule?

You're encountering an error deep in the platform guts, open a support case. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs for more info.

Does this answer your question? Error on uninstalling package via apex
